# How to reverse "-force-opengl" in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

For performance reasons, I have set `-force-opengl` in the `Unity Hub` shortcut in Windows (in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`).

However, now I want the settings to be reverted back, and simply removing it doesn't do that.

Is there other place to change the settings? Or what is the other option that does the reverse of `-force-opengl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your project go to the `Player Settings` → `Other Settings`

Now in case there is the `Auto Graphics API for XY` (XY = your target Platform) or only `AutoGraphics API` (for non Standalone Platforms) enabled  then **disable** it

[image]

This makes priority the List(s) `Graphics APIs for XY` / `Graphics APIs` appear where you can add and order and the desired API(s)

[image]